# Why do I get unhandled promise errors here

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to fetch API data and then once I receive that API data I want to then store it in my backend by saving it to MongoDB. I am using node and express to do this. This is the error I'm getting currently:

```
(node:9072) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\simer\Downloads\Talkhappi\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\simer\Downloads\Talkhappi\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\simer\Downloads\Talkhappi\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:278:15)
    at createUserData (C:\Users\simer\Downloads\Talkhappi\server\controllers\userDataController.js:93:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:9072) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either 
by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9072) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is my code:

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
// create new user data
const createUserData = async (req, res) => {
    const {id, scores, transcript} = req.body
    const user_id = req.user._id

    const configuration = new Configuration({
        apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
    });
    const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

    // feedback
    const response = await openai.createCompletion({
        model: "text-davinci-002",
        prompt: "Provide personal feedback for me and give me tips: " + transcript,
        temperature: 1,
        max_tokens: 200,
        top_p: 1,
        frequency_penalty: 0,
        presence_penalty: 0,
    });

    // score
    const response2 = await openai.createCompletion({
        model: "text-davinci-002",
        prompt: "Give this text a number from 1-100 in terms of positivity: " + transcript,
        temperature: 1,
        max_tokens: 100,
        top_p: 1,
        frequency_penalty: 0,
        presence_penalty: 0,
    });

    // console.log(response.data.choices[0].text)
    // console.log(response2.data.choices)

    const newUserData = new UserData({
        id: 'user',
        scores: response2.data.choices[0].text,
        transcript: transcript,
        user_id: user_id,
        feedback: response.data.choices[0].text
    })

    console.log(newUserData)
    // add doc to db
    try {
        await newUserData.save()
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({error: error.message})
    }

    console.log('POST:', newUserData)
    return res.status(201).json({user_data: newUserData, feedback: response.data.choices[0].text, score: response2.data.choices[0].text})
}
```

How can I properly write this async code to properly do the things I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

The likely root of that error is that when the code executes:

```
res.status(400).json({error: error.message})
```

it then falls through and also executes:

```
return res.status(201).json({user_data: newUserData, feedback: response.data.choices[0].text, score: response2.data.choices[0].text})
```

That attempts to send two responses to the same incoming request and gives you the `ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT` error.

You can fix just that issue by adding a return:

```
res.status(400).json({error: error.message});
return;
```

so the code doesn't fall through to the other `res.send()`.

---

But, there's more to complete error handling here because you aren't handling any errors from the `await` statements in this function.

You can capture errors from the other `await` statements like this:

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
// create new user data
const createUserData = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { id, scores, transcript } = req.body
        const user_id = req.user._id

        const configuration = new Configuration({
            apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
        });
        const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

        // feedback
        const response = await openai.createCompletion({
            model: "text-davinci-002",
            prompt: "Provide personal feedback for me and give me tips: " + transcript,
            temperature: 1,
            max_tokens: 200,
            top_p: 1,
            frequency_penalty: 0,
            presence_penalty: 0,
        });

        // score
        const response2 = await openai.createCompletion({
            model: "text-davinci-002",
            prompt: "Give this text a number from 1-100 in terms of positivity: " + transcript,
            temperature: 1,
            max_tokens: 100,
            top_p: 1,
            frequency_penalty: 0,
            presence_penalty: 0,
        });

        // console.log(response.data.choices[0].text)
        // console.log(response2.data.choices)

        const newUserData = new UserData({
            id: 'user',
            scores: response2.data.choices[0].text,
            transcript: transcript,
            user_id: user_id,
            feedback: response.data.choices[0].text
        })

        console.log(newUserData)
        // add doc to db
        await newUserData.save();
        console.log('POST:', newUserData)
        res.status(201).json({ user_data: newUserData, feedback: response.data.choices[0].text, score: response2.data.choices[0].text })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(400).json({ error: error.message })
    }
}
```